# PHP Password Protect

Tags: php, forms, passwords, password-protection

I have been researching for so long, and I've done this hundreds of times, but I forgot now.  The simplest thing.  How to password protect in PHP.  Please help, when I click submit, nothing pops up.  Here's my code:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#textbox1 {
text-shadow:2px 2px 3px #000000;
}

label {
text-shadow:2px 2px 3px #000000;
font-family:"Arial";
}
</style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearText(target){target.value= "";}
</script>
<head>
<center>
<form action="" method="POST">
<label face="Arial">Password:  </label><input id="textbox1" type="password" name="password" value="" onfocus="clearText(this)">
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Login to Uploader">
</form>
</center>
</html>
<?php

$pass = $_POST['password'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ($pass == "pengsuploader123" || $pass="pass") {
echo "Test";
} else {
echo "Wrong!";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't have anything with `name=submit`, that's why `isset($_POST['submit'])===FALSE` always

Comment: Your HTML markup burns my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your submit button the attribute `name="submit"` for PHP to detect it.  Additionally, `$pass="pass"` should be `$pass == "pass"`.

Comment: thanks man!  Can you help me with something else also/

Comment: @Ryan You should probably ask it as a question rather than ask a specific person, unless it's related to this code.

Comment: It is.  I want to make this so they have to login to this form to view a specific page.  So like, they have to go to the pass protect page and if they enter the correct password they can view a specific document, and make it so they can't access the documment directly.  I can't make a new question because i have to wait 20 min

Comment: You'll need to use cookies/sessions, and mod_rewrite if the document is stored to be externally available or readfile if not. There are plenty of tutorials on how to make a login system.